# Unable to show legend in seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

I am new to plotting in python and trying following code to plot distribution in `seaborn` but unable to see the legend, i.e., `test_label1` and `test_label1` on the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

plt.figure("Test Plots")
lst1 = list(np.random.rand(10))
lst2 = list(np.random.rand(10))
sns.distplot(lst1, label='test_label1', color="0.25")
sns.distplot(lst2, label='test_label2', color="0.25")

plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.legend()`?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. This works but the only problem with this is that I have to do it separately at the end. So something like `plt.legend(['test_label1', 'test_label2'])` will require to remember the ordering.

Comment: You don't have to do that as you have already specified `label=` in your plot. Calling `plt.legend()` before `plt.show()` will work (it does for me)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As you have already labelled your plots using `label=` inside your `sns.distplot` then all you have to do is show your legend. This is done by adding `plt.legend()` just before `plt.show()`

More information on matplotlib legends can be found in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

Comment: Is that really the "Seaborn way", to use matplotlib directly for a legend?

Comment: @matanster I don't really see any problem because seaborn is essentially just a wrapper for matplotlib anyway. There are ways to get a legend to appear using just arguments of `sns.distplot`, however IMO it's not as simple

Answer (score 11):

By using [`fig.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) we can show legends in the distribution plot.
Here, an argument array of `labels` is passed to the function.
Labels in the legend will also be displayed as an order of array values.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
lst1 = list(np.random.rand(10))
lst2 = list(np.random.rand(10))
sns.distplot(lst1)
sns.distplot(lst1)
fig.legend(labels=['test_label1','test_label2'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered as low quality posts, [edit] your answer and add some explanation

Answer (score 4):

I found some issue using "**fig.legend()**" to adding **labels** into **legend** in **seaborn histogram**. It reverse colors order in legend without changing colors of histogram bars...

```
fig.legend(labels=['label1','label2',...])
```

[Histogram before using fig.legend()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR2I3.png)

[Histogram after using fig.legend()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrz2k.png)

Modules versions:

- seborn '0.11.0'
- matplotlib '3.1.3'

Simple solution is to reverse the order of `label_list` by appling `label_list.reverse()` but I don't consider it as good solution. I don't have idea what is happening and how to block reversing the order of colors in legend.